# Update list of unique items in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I am creating a JSON file that will have unique values from each column of a csv. What I am doing right now is generating a dictionary with unique values of each column stored as a separate entry (the column name being the key).

I have to download a new version of the csv regularly and update the meta-data JSON. My current plan is to download only the latest update to the csv (we’re using Elastic Search), read off the unique values from the csv, update my meta-data JSON, and then concatenate the new and the old csv’s.

Questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way to do this? The old csv is ~10GB, 51M rows, 1400 columns; it takes a day to generate the JSON. Here’s my current code:

.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import json 

filename = sys.argv[1]
json_file = sys.argv[2]

def get_col_stats(colname, numrows=None):
    print('start reading ' + colname)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, engine='c', usecols=[colname], nrows = numrows)
    print('finished reading ' + colname)

    df.columns = ['col']
    uniq = list(df.col.unique())
    count = len(uniq)
    print('unique count is', count, '\n')

    if colname in ['orderYear', 'faultDate', 'faultActiveTime']:
        return {'type': 'date', 'min': df.col.dropna().min(), 'max': df.col.dropna().max()}
    elif count < 1000 or colname == 'faultCode':
        return {'type': 'factor', 'uniq': uniq}
    else:
        return {'type': 'continuous', 'min': df.col.dropna().min(), 'max': df.col.dropna().max()}

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, np.integer): return int(o)
    raise TypeError


col_list = list(pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=1).columns)
print(col_list[1:50])

d = {}

for i in col_list:
    d[i] = get_col_stats(i, numrows=None) 
    print('made ' + i)
    with open(json_file, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(d, fp, default=default)
```

2. Is there a better way to update a dictionary with unique values than this:

.

```
 dic = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [3,4,5]}
 dic['a'].extend([2,3,4])
 dic['a'] = list(set(dic['a'])) 
 dic
```

Comment: It looks like you read the entire 10G file into memory to process. Have you considered the `chunksize` parameter of `read_csv`? You then do this multiple times - why not update the dictionary for every column as you read through the file just once?

Comment: I know and use chunking all the time, but in this case, I need to get unique values (or range) from the whole columns, so chunking by rows doesn’t really make sense. But, also, I don’t read the entire 10G into memory; I do it column by column (first I read in the column names, then I cycle through them, read in just one column, get unique values, and update the dictionary/json).

Comment: OK but the entire 10G is parsed once per column instead of just once, and the entire column is held in memory which could be very wasteful if many values are the same (unless duplicates are somehow stored efficiently, but I doubt it). Since you're holding all the unique values in memory anyway I say you initialise the dict with empty sets for all the columns and then update every column each time you read in a small chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure on your first question, as I'm not familiar with pandas. But for question 2, it's much easier to do:

```
dic = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [3,4,5]}
dic['a'] = list(set(dic['a'] + [2,3,4]))
dic
```

Answer (score 1):

given the volumes, I'd stay well away from re-creating a list from a set each time.  Just keep them as sets.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in [("a", [1,2,3]), ("b", [3,4,5])]:
    dic[k].update(v)

print ("dic[0]:%s" % dic)

dic['a'].update([2,3,4])
dic['c'].update(["00",99])

print ("dic[1]:%s" % dic)
```

output:

```
dic[0]:defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'a': set([1, 2, 3]), 'b': set([3, 4, 5])})

dic[1]:defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'a': set([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'c': set(['00', 99]), 'b': set([3, 4, 5])})
```